# How to store/aggregate correlated cdc events with flink?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, cdc

I have a kafka queue where multiple cdc events are coming from a database.
Suppose the following three tables implementing a student-course n:n association:

```
STUDENT
COURSE
STUDENT_COURSE
```

I can have the following "business" events:

1. A new student enrolls to a course: in this case I would receive **3 events** on my kafka queue, said events can come in any order but I'd like to emit a "business" event like this one: `{type:"enroll", "student": {"name": "Jhon", "age": "..}, "course": {"name":"physics", "teacher":"Foo", ...}`
2. A student changes their course: in this case I would only receive **1 event on my kafka queue** (on STUDENT_COURSE) and I'd launch a "business" event like this one: `{"type": "change", "student": {"name": "Jhon", "age": "..}, "newcourse": {"name":"maths", "teacher":"Foo", ...}`
3. Updates on STUDENT information (say email, phone,...) or COURSE information (time, teacher,...) 1 event on either table

My issue is that I don't know how to store and correlate said CDC to make a business event together, in fact I'd need to do something like this:

1. Receive the event and store it in an "uncertain" state, wait for a reasonable time, say 10 sec
2. If an event on another table is received then I'm in case 1
3. Otherwise I'm in 2/3

Is there a way to obtain this behavior in flink?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you could start with a streaming SQL join on the 3 dynamic tables derived from these CDC streams, which will produce an update stream along the lines of what you're looking for.

Some of the examples in https://github.com/ververica/flink-sql-cookbook should provide inspiration for getting started. https://github.com/ververica/flink-sql-CDC and https://github.com/ververica/flink-cdc-connectors are also good resources.